# Ask the help about the AndroidManifest.xml reading issue

Tags: java, android, xml, email

**1.The problematic scenario:**

Our product is based on aosp 4.4. When I build the whole system with adding ar_EG locale to our product, there will be a error log during the first booting procedure, additionally if I build the system without the ar_EG locale, the problem will not come out.

```
01-01 08:01:38.711 W/PackageParser( 529): /system/app/Email.apk (at Binary XML file line #357): <provider> does not include authorities attribute
```

And this error will lead to the dysfunction of Email app, finally the crash dialog message of Exchange will show. The crash log is below:

```
01-01 09:18:53.475 E/AndroidRuntime(  982): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 09:18:53.475 E/AndroidRuntime(  982): Process: com.android.exchange, PID: 982
01-01 09:18:53.475 E/AndroidRuntime(  982): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.android.exchange.Exchange: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI content://com.android.email.provider
01-01 09:18:53.475 E/AndroidRuntime(  982):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4331)
01-01 09:18:53.475 E/AndroidRuntime(  982):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-01 09:18:53.475 E/AndroidRuntime(  982):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-01 09:18:53.475 E/AndroidRuntime(  982):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-01 09:18:53.475 E/AndroidRuntime(  982):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-01 09:18:53.475 E/AndroidRuntime(  982):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5008)
01-01 09:18:53.475 E/AndroidRuntime(  982):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 09:18:53.475 E/AndroidRuntime(  982):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-01 09:18:53.475 E/AndroidRuntime(  982):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
01-01 09:18:53.475 E/AndroidRuntime(  982):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
01-01 09:18:53.475 E/AndroidRuntime(  982):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 09:18:53.475 E/AndroidRuntime(  982): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI content://com.android.email.provider
01-01 09:18:53.475 E/AndroidRuntime(  982):     at android.content.ContentResolver.call(ContentResolver.java:1352)
01-01 09:18:53.475 E/AndroidRuntime(  982):     at com.android.exchange.Exchange.onCreate(Exchange.java:34)
01-01 09:18:53.475 E/AndroidRuntime(  982):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
01-01 09:18:53.475 E/AndroidRuntime(  982):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4328)
01-01 09:18:53.475 E/AndroidRuntime(  982):     ... 10 more
```

**2. My investigations**

Firstly, I must say the Email's AndroidManifest.xml is not touched, I just add some Arabic strings into Email.

I tracked the related source code in    *$(aosp_dir)/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/ PackageParser.java*, inside the function called:

```
private Provider parseProvider(Package owner, Resources res,
         XmlPullParser parser, AttributeSet attrs, int flags, String[] outError)
```

After reading the authorities of the current provider defined in Email's Androidmanifest.xml:

```
String cpname = sa.getNonConfigurationString(
             com.android.internal.R.styleable.AndroidManifestProvider_authorities, 0);
```

It always return NULL, therefore the error exception will show.

Then I noticed that the reason why getNonConfigurationString return null is that the TypedArray got from the start of  parseProvider is problematic:

```
TypedArray sa = res.obtainAttributes(attrs,
             com.android.internal.R.styleable.AndroidManifestProvider);
```

"TypedArray sa" is a long array with that the six elements is the bigger element, and the com.android.internal.R.styleable.AndroidManifestProvider_authorities indicate that the authorities is the 10th bigger element, so I printed the contents of sa under the both scenarios: the successful case without AR_EG locale and the failed case with AR_EG locale. So I just show the authorities' elements:

```
The successful case:  3, 188, -1,          0, 0, 0,
The failed case:      3, 1127, 2, 2131362092, 4, 0
```

From the source code, I have known that the fifth element of a bigger element is a kind of config called STYLE_CHANGING_CONFIGURATIONS, we can see that the value of this config under the failed case is 4, this can lead that  sa.getNonConfigurationString return null.

Therefore I continue to track source codes to identify the origin of the problematic value:

```
     android_content_AssetManager_retrieveAttributes  in frameworks\base\core\jni\android_util_AssetManager.cpp
                                                ||
                                                ||
                                                \/
     ResTable::resolveReference in frameworks\base\libs\androidfw\ResourceTypes.cpp
                                               ||
                                               ||
                                               \/
     ResTable::getResource in frameworks\base\libs\androidfw\ResourceTypes.cpp
```

The source code show me the config value is from the typeSpecFlags in struct ResTable::Type finally.

**3. My doubts**

Currently I am confusing in these codes, so I write them on stackoverflow to ask the help, maybe you guys are very familiar with related source codes or met the similar scenario. I still don't know how to get the typeSpecFlags in struct ResTable::Type, and I think that the reading process is related with locale. I hope that you can give me some hints. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have found the problematic location. If the final android image includes AR locales, android's resource manager can't get the valid string from the AndroidManifest.xml via string referencing method. For instance:

```
android:authorities="@string/eml_attachment_provider"
```

Once the procedure of parsing onr provider fail, the whole parsing process of AndroidManifest.xml will be terminated. Therefore, the rest components in AndroidManifest.xml will all be invalid.